# Two ways to get a homomorphism $ \mathscr O_{Y,f(x)}\to \mathscr O_{X,x} $

Tags: sheaf-theory

Let $ (f,f^\flat)\colon (X,\mathscr O_X)\to (Y,\mathscr O_Y) $ be a morphism of ringed spaces (i.e., let $ f\colon X\to Y $ be continuous and let $ f^\flat\colon \mathscr O_Y\to f_*\mathscr O_X $ be a morphism of sheaves).

Let $ x\in X $. There are at least two ways to obtain a ring homomorphism
$$
f_x\colon \mathscr O_{Y,f(x)}\to \mathscr O_{X,x}\text{.}
$$

On one hand, we can say that $ f_x $ is the unique map making the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathscr O_Y(V) @>{({-})_{f(x)}}>> \mathscr O_{Y,f(x)}\\
@V{f_V^\flat}VV @VV{f_x}V\\
\mathscr O_X(f^*V) @>{({-})_x}>> \mathscr O_{X,x}
\end{CD}
$$
commutative for every open subset $ V\subset Y $ containing $ f(x) $, i.e., such that
$$
f_x(t_{f(x)}) = f_V^\flat(t)_x
$$
for every $ t\in \mathscr O_Y(V) $.

On the other, we can consider the adjoint sheaf map $ f^\flat\colon f^*\mathscr O_Y\to \mathscr O_X $ and take the stalk at $ x $
$$
f_x^\sharp\colon (f^*\mathscr O_Y)_x\to \mathscr O_{X,x}
$$
and then compose $ f_x^\sharp $ with the canonical isomorphism
$$
\mathscr O_{Y,f(x)} \cong (f^*\mathscr O_Y)_x
$$
to get a map $ f_x\colon \mathscr O_{Y,f(x)}\to \mathscr O_{X,x} $.

I was trying to convince me that both the maps $ f_x $ that I have obtained are indeed the same, but I got stuck.

Is there an arrow nonsense way to prove this fact?